# Cannot combine two models into a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I have been trying to get two models to appear in a single view using ViewModels but am failing.

I have simple view with 3 fields right now (Comment, Name, Department) and and a model to match it.  I have a controller that returns an empty view and when you submit the form, the empty model is filled in and passed back to the controller.  I now want to turn the department field into a drop down and have deduced (maybe incorrectly?) that I should create another model with the static values in it and then pass the ViewModel to the view via the controller but when I attempt to do this, it fails:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="fieldset">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>CommentDb</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new {style = "width: 900px; height:200px;", autocomplete = "off" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Your Name")
                @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentByName)*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CommentByName, new { autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "Optional" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentByName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Your Department", new { @class = "display-label" })
                @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department)*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Department, new { autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "Optional" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submit"/>
    </div>

}
```

**Department drop down model:**

```
namespace SuggestionBox.Models
{
    public class DropDownModel
    {
        public String Departments { get; set; }

        public String SetDropDownList()
        {
            Departments = "Engineering";

            return Departments;
        }
    }
}
```

**Database model:**

```
namespace SuggestionBox.Models
{
    public class CommentModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int CommentiD { get; set; }
        public string CommentByName { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SuggestionBox.Models
{
    public class CommentDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public CommentDbContext() : base()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CommentDbContext, SuggestionBox.Migrations.Configuration>());
        }

        public DbSet<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My attempted ViewModel:**

```
namespace SuggestionBox.ViewModels
{
    public class SuggestionBoxViewModel
    {
        public CommentModel Comments { get; set; }
        public DropDownModel Departments { get; set; }

        public SuggestionBoxViewModel()
        {
            Departments = new DropDownModel();
            Departments.SetDropDownList();

            Comments = new CommentModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Controller:**

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        SuggestionBoxViewModel vm = new SuggestionBoxViewModel();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

In `return View(vm);`, the IDE says: **Arguement type 'SuggestionBox.ViewModels.SuggestionBoxViewModel' is not assignable to the model type 'SuggestionBox.Models.CommentModel'**

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Cheers.

Comment: Looks like you're specifying a model type of `CommentModel` instead of `SuggestionBoxViewModel` in your view.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  That was it!! DUH!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a simple task into something overly complex.  Your view model should contain only the properties used in the view, and should not contain methods. Populating your view model properties is the responsibility of the controller.

View model

```
public class CommentModelVM
{
  [Required]
  public string Comment { get; set; }
  public string CommentByName { get; set; }
  [Display(Name="Your Department")] // add attributes associated with the view
  public string Department { get; set; }
  public SelectList DepartmentList { get; set } // to populate the dropdown options
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CommentModelVM model = new CommentModelVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Create(CommentModelVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid())
  {
    // Repopulate options and return view
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // Save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(CommentModelVM model)
{
  List<string> departments = // create your list of departments here (from database or static list)
  model.DepartmentList = new SelectList(departments);
}
```

View

```
....
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Department)    
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, Model.DepartmentList)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to start by saying that generally it is a bad idea to name properties or classes for our ViewModels out the view controls that they are bound to. For example: DropDownModel. Doing this creates confusion since Models and ViewModels don't represent a UI component they represent entities and data that the view uses to render its UI controls.

With that being said to answer you question I don't see the need for a ViewModel class to represent the static list of departments for your dropdown. I think you should just add a new list of departments to your SuggestionBoxViewModel class like this:

```
namespace SuggestionBox.ViewModels
{
    public class SuggestionBoxViewModel
    {
        public CommentModel Comments { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> Departments { get; set; }

        public string SelectedDepartment { get; set; }

        public SuggestionBoxViewModel()
        {
            Departments = new [] {"Engineering","Sales"};

            Comments = new CommentModel();
        }

        public int CommentiD 
        { 
            get { return Comments.CommentiD; }
        }

        public string CommentByName 
        { 
            get { return Comments.CommentByName; }
        }        
    }
}
```

Then in your view all you have to do is bind the dropdown to the list of departments. Like this:

At the top of your view:

```
@model SuggestionBox.ViewModels.SuggestionBoxViewModel
```

Then where you want the dropdown to display:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, new SelectList(Model.Departments))
```

And that's it! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @alejosoft.  This was extremely helpful.  Can you, however, explain your first paragraph?  I'd like to ensure my naming conventions are correct for the future.

Comment: I mean that you should keep a clear separation between your data objects (Models and ViewModels) and the UI elements (like dropdowns, text boxes, etc)... So it is a bad practice to name a ViewModel with something like GenderRadioButtonViewModel or DropDownViewModel. Does it make sense?

Comment: I believe so. What you are saying is that, instead of calling the Model: DropDown..., it should be something about the data instead of the UI element where that data will appear, e.g. DepartmentModel.

Answer (score 0):

Your View seems to expect a Comment Model.

If you wanted to bind to a ViewModel, then you would have to implement all the properties that Comment exposes.

So your ViewModel might look like this:

```
namespace SuggestionBox.ViewModels
{
    public class SuggestionBoxViewModel
    {
        public CommentModel Comments { get; set; }
        public DropDownModel Departments { get; set; }

        public SuggestionBoxViewModel()
        {
            Departments = new DropDownModel();
            Departments.SetDropDownList();

            Comments = new CommentModel();
        }

        public int CommentiD 
        { 
            get { return Comments.CommentiD; }
        }

        public string CommentByName 
        { 
            get { return Comments.CommentByName; }
        }

        ...etc.
    }
}
```